# Creating global event handlers using WithEvents for a GUI application in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, user-interface, event-handling

To get familiar with VB, I'm working on a frontend for a cli application by taking input from a user and feeding it as command line parameters to the said backend application. Here's a link to the [repository](https://github.com/vaibhav-y/bsc-gui/tree/changes-manga) for reference of any kind.
Also, I'm fairly new to VB/GUI programming, so please excuse the obvious things that I must have missed out on.

**A little background on my thought process:**

Here is how I thought I would handle events in the application to build my args string, excuse me if I'm being too verbose, but I thought it would be best to describe what I'm doing as best as I can before I tell what the exact problem is

1. GUI has various components
2. Each component has public events that are fired relevantly
3. A class (ArgBuilder) listens to these events in the background and updates related variables
4. The handler for the 'OK' button, instantiates this class to get the command and creates a new background process using an already available executable.

**The question:**

My problem lies within (3), whenever I try to say, handle the InFileSelected event from CtlInputFile class (or any Class.PublicEventFromThatClass ) I get an error `Handles clause requires WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types`.

So far, the [MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) have helped, but the issues in this one's a bit harder to grasp.

What have I missed in say this class as an example:

```
Public Class CtlInputFile
    Public Event InFileSelected(ByVal inFileName As String)
    Dim inFileName As String

    ' Proxy Init Module
    Private Sub ctlInputFile_Initialize()
        inFileName = String.Empty
    End Sub

    ' Event handlers below
End Class
```

And the global event listener that should be able to capture `CtlInputFile.InFileSelected(inFileName)`

```
Public Class ArgBuilder
    ' Create getters and setters for all relevant vars in the project
    ' Capture events from all over the place
    Dim inFileName As String

    Private Sub ctlInputFile_FileSelected(ByVal inFilename As String) Handles _
    ctlInput.InFileSelected
        ' Do something useful
    End Sub

End Class
```

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see something like `Handles Button1.Click`, this means that there is an object defined like this

```
Public WithEvents Button1 As New Button
```

This code is usually located in the Designer file of a form (you need to select Display all Files to see it). This allows you to then handle this events by adding the Handles clause to a method with the correct declaration.

In your case you would need to create the object `ctlInput` like

```
Public WithEvents ctlInput As New CtlInputFile
```

if you want to use the `Handles` clause.
Another possibility is to wire up the events by hand using `AddHandler`:

```
Addhandler ctlInput.InFileSelected, AddressOf ctlInputFile_FileSelected
```

This works even without the WithEvents statement.

The last would be the way to go if you want to have a central place where you handle events. You could place the event handling code in a module or use static methods (Shared) in a class:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler Me.ResizeEnd, AddressOf EventHandlers.FormResized
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class EventHandlers
    Public Shared Sub FormResized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox(sender.ToString & " was resized!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

You then wire up the events during initilization.